# Is there a way to access a subfield in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

Is there a way to access a field within a field in a Hibernate entity object using syntax along the lines of `fieldName.subFieldName`?

I realize you can do this by using `criteria.createCriteria("fieldName")` then get add restrictions or whatever to the subfield, but I was wondering if there was a terser way to accomplish this.

Comment: Do you mean in HQL?  What is the relationship between the object you are querying on and the field?  Are you looking for a property on a one-to-one relationship or one-to-many?

Comment: I don't mean in HQL but through the Criteria class. This would be a one to one relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an alias.

From the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-associations),

> There is also an alternate form that is useful in certain circumstances:
>
> ```
> List cats = sess.createCriteria(Cat.class)
>     .createAlias("kittens", "kt")
>     .createAlias("mate", "mt")
>     .add( Restrictions.eqProperty("kt.name", "mt.name") )
>     .list();
> ```

Comment: Ah so you need to make aliases to access the fields with another field? Strange that you can just do it without using the full field name.